# Ordering Post by Meta Key (Not Working)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

So I've read all the stack exchange posts on this, and I feel like what I have, based on what I've read, should be working. I'm a little confused as to why it isn't.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'events_startdate',
    'order_by' => 'meta_value',
  );

  $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
```

I should mention that in my loop I have echo'd out my meta_key to make sure it's returning the correct info:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'events_startdate', true); ?>
```

And by my estimation it is. It's spitting out a nice round number like this: `1545091200`

This looks to me like it should work, but it doesn't. Anyone see anything glaring that I'm missing?

Comment: try this 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

Comment: I have tried that already as well and not getting anything different in my order.

Comment: Just to add a note, I'm echoing out the value on each card just so I can make sure each has the correct meta_key value, and the order by ascending numbers is coming out: 2, 3, 4, 1 

So its ordering them by post creation despite being told to order by meta_key

My only thought is the meta value isn't coming out correctly - but in my test echo, it looks like it is.

Comment: 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC'

Comment: Is your round number an example of the meta value? Or is it stored in some other format? The format is rather important here as anything other than a basic number won't necessarily be interpreted the way you think it will.

Comment: @vikrantzilpe - tried that, no luck.

@WebElaine I think it is. `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'events_startdate', true); ?>` is the function I'm using to display it in each card, and that function should be grabbing the meta_value associated to `events_startdate`. I'm not sure how else to ensure my data is correct.

Comment: So flipping ASC and DESC as the sort order _does_ flip the order. So it is doing _something_. I'm just not sure how the order is being determined. My echo statement is giving me what I believe is the meta value for each post, but it's ordering them as such: `1543536000 , 1545264000 , 1545177600 , 1545091200`. This order makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you inspect `$post_query` after you run the query, you will see how all of the query vars are set and the actual SQL being sent to the database.

Comment: Ran this: `<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>` and got this: 

`SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '195') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`.

I don't understand why it's saying order by post date when it's clearly been set to order by meta_value.

Comment: @Milo - Reran it against `echo $post_query->request;` and got this: 

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (3) ) ) AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'events_startdate' ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10`

So more correct info, but still isn't picking up the order by field.

Comment: Do you have any other plugins or code that might be filtering the query? Something like, say, a `pre_get_posts` filter that's overly broad? (I usually check for this with something like `global $wp_filter; var_dump( $wp_filters['pre_get_posts'] );`

Comment: @PatJ I'm using a plugin for my meta box creation. So `events_startdate` is definitely being touched by that. What I'm really lost on is figuring out A) what `meta_key` is looking for value-wise in its pairing (according to the Codex, it's a string), and B) How to accurately check the value of what I'm plugging in. As I'm sure you can see, I'm attempting to check it all, but I feel there must be something I'm doing that's changing the value that's being input into my query because when I do my test echo, it's a string, and it looks exactly how I think it should look to be successful.

Comment: I've actually dug into the Wordpress database and searched out the posts to make sure the meta key I'm using exists as expected, and it does. I'm fairly positive the plugin is not the issue. There doesn't seem to be any logical reason why it won't work.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. Posts seems to be ordered randomly and definitely not by the meta_value order. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Damn, I wish I could help, but I'm no longer at that job and don't have access to the code base. It was long enough ago that I cannot remember what the issue was, but I must have fixed it. I don't envy you.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Have spent like few hours searching for the problem and it turned out to be just a typo: instead of incorrect `order_by` you should use `orderby` -  without the underscore. So, this should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key'  => 'events_startdate',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
  );

  $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) {...}
  }
```